# Code to support different measurement systems

Tags: java, beginner, android, converting, unit-conversion

I am developing an application in which the user can use different measurement systems. Currently, 
there is support for the metric and imperial measurement systems. To support these systems, I wrote a converter. Could you take a look at its code and tell how can it be improved.

```
public class SystemsMeasuresConverter {

private Context context;
private Profile profile;

public SystemsMeasuresConverter(Context context, Profile profile) {
    this.context = context;
    this.profile = profile;
}

/**
 * Converts mass from some units to some units
 *
 * @param input mass in some units
 * @return mass some units
 */
public Number convertToMassUnit(Number input, SystemsMeasures from, SystemsMeasures to) {
    double constant = 1;

    switch (from) {
        case Imperial:
            if (to == Metric) {
                constant = 0.455;
            }
            break;
        case Metric:
            if (to == Imperial) {
                constant = 2.2;
            }
            break;
    }

    return MathUtil.round(input.doubleValue() * constant, MathUtil.GLOBAL_SCALE);
}

/**
 * Converts mass from some units to units selected in profile
 *
 * @param input mass in some units
 * @return mass in units of measurements selected in the user profile
 */
public Number convertToMassUnit(Number input, SystemsMeasures from) {
    return convertToMassUnit(input, from, profile.getSystemMeasures());
}

/**
 * Converts mass from kilograms to units selected in profile
 *
 * @param input metric system
 * @return mass in units of measurements selected in the user profile
 */
public Number convertToMassUnit(Number input) {
    return convertToMassUnit(input, Metric, profile.getSystemMeasures());
}

/**
 * Converts distance from units selected in profile to kilograms
 *
 * @param input metric system
 * @return distance in units of measurements selected in the user profile
 */
public Number convertToKg(Number input) {
    return convertToMassUnit(input, profile.getSystemMeasures(), SystemsMeasures.Metric);
}

/**
 * Returns abbreviations for mass units selected in profile
 *
 * @return abbreviations for mass units selected in profile
 */
public String getStringFromCurrentMassUnit() {
    SystemsMeasures unit = profile.getSystemMeasures();
    switch (unit) {
        case Metric:
            return context.getString(R.string.kilogramsMassUnit);
        case Imperial:
            return context.getString(R.string.poundsMassUnit);
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Cannot find Mass Unit");
}

/**
 * Converts distance from some units to some units
 *
 * @param input mass in some units
 * @return mass some units
 */
public Number convertToDistanceUnits(Number input, SystemsMeasures from, SystemsMeasures to) {
    double constant = 1;

    switch (from) {
        case Imperial:
            if (to == Metric) {
                constant = 2.54;
            }
            break;
        case Metric:
            if (to == Imperial) {
                constant = 0.394;
            }
            break;
    }

    return MathUtil.round(input.doubleValue() * constant, MathUtil.GLOBAL_SCALE);
}

/**
 * Converts distance from some units to units selected in profile
 *
 * @param input distance in some units
 * @return distance in units of measurements selected in the user profile
 */
public Number convertToDistanceUnits(Number input, SystemsMeasures from) {
    return convertToDistanceUnits(input, from, profile.getSystemMeasures());
}

/**
 * Converts distance from meters to units selected in profile
 *
 * @param input metric system
 * @return distance in units of measurements selected in the user profile
 */
public Number convertToDistanceUnits(Number input) {
    return convertToDistanceUnits(input, Metric, profile.getSystemMeasures());
}

/**
 * Converts distance from units selected in profile to meters
 *
 * @param input metric system
 * @return distance in units of measurements selected in the user profile
 */
public Number convertToMeter(Number input) {
    return convertToDistanceUnits(input, profile.getSystemMeasures(), SystemsMeasures.Metric);
}

/**
 * Returns abbreviations for distance units selected in profile
 *
 * @return abbreviations for distance units selected in profile
 */
public String getStringFromCurrentDistanceUnit() {
    SystemsMeasures unit = profile.getSystemMeasures();
    switch (unit) {
        case Metric:
            return context.getString(R.string.meters_distance_unit);
        case Imperial:
            return context.getString(R.string.feet_distance_unit);
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Cannot find Mass Unit");
  }
}
```

SystemsMeasures

```
public enum SystemsMeasures {
    Metric(0),
    Imperial(1);

    private final int value;

    SystemsMeasures(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue(){
        return value;
    }

    public static SystemsMeasures getById(int id) {
        for (SystemsMeasures e : values()) {
            if (e.value == id) return e;
        }
        return Metric;
    }
}
```

Comment: attributes should be private and accessible using getters/setters. In your case, `context` and `profile` are package private.

Comment: I think `getById()` could technically be improved by storing the enums in a `HashMap` or something like this additionally but I don't think there are performance improvements as thete ate only two elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest changing `SystemsMeasures` to

```
public enum SystemsMeasures {
    Metric(1.0,1.0),
    Imperial(2.54,0.455);

    public final double lengthFactor;
    public final double massFactor;

    SystemsMeasures(double lengthFactor,double massFactor) {
        this.lengthUnit = lengthUnit;
        this.lengthFactor = lengthFactor;
    }
}
```

Then you can just write for example

```
/**
 * Converts mass from some units to some units
 *
 * @param input mass in some units
 * @return mass some units
 */
public Number convertToMassUnit(Number input, SystemsMeasures from, SystemsMeasures to) {
    return MathUtil.round(input.doubleValue() * from.MassFactor/to.MassFactor, MathUtil.GLOBAL_SCALE);
}
```

Comment: It seems to me to use LengthUnit and MassUnit will be superfluous, since this does not affect the work of the code and does not make any sense

Comment: @Destroyer. You're right. I think that I added them for simplification of `getStringFromCurrentMassUnit()` and `getStringFromCurrentDistanceUnit()`.

Comment: These lines are in R.string. Therefore, for implementation, you need to use not string but id string, and i will have to use context in enum. In general, I think this is a bad idea.

Comment: @Destroyer. I approved your edit. You know more about the context than I do.

Answer (score 2):

I would replace all the switch statements with a Map.
Map key should be pair of from-to `SystemsMeasures`. Map value can be a container class that holds all conversion factors.
You can write custom `Pair` or `Tuple` class or use ready made one from libraries such as Apache commons, Guava, etc.
The container class can be something like

```
public class ConversionFactor {
    public double mass;
    public double distance;
    public ConversionFactor(double mass, double distance) {
        this.mass = mass;
        this.distance = distance;
    }
}
```

The map can be defined (assuming [Apache commons Pair](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html) which correctly implements `equals()` and `hashCode()`)

```
Map<Pair<SystemsMeasures, SystemsMeasures>, ConversionFactor>
```

Now, you just need to create a `Pair` instance that represents the requested conversion and `get()` the value from the map.

an added advantage of this approach is that you can easily load the map values from file, avoiding [magic numbers anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))

Example:

```
public static Map<Pair<SystemsMeasures, SystemsMeasures>, ConversionFactor> conversionMap =
    Map.of(
        new ImmutablePair<>(SystemsMeasures.Metric, SystemsMeasures.Imperial),
            new ConversionFactor(2.2, 0.394),
        new ImmutablePair<>(SystemsMeasures.Imperial, SystemsMeasures.Metric),
            new ConversionFactor(0.455, 2.54)
    );

public Number convertToMassUnit(Number input, SystemsMeasures from, SystemsMeasures to) {
    double constant = conversionMap.get(new ImmutablePair<>(from, to)).mass;
    return ... 
}
```

The above map can be represented in serialized form:

```
Metric, Imperial -> 2.2, 0.394
Imperial, Metric -> 0.455, 2.54
```

read the file into `List<String>` and parse it into the map.

Comment: Could you give some examples of this? (code, examples, articles)

Comment: see edited code

Comment: Why did you reject the change? Initially, the question rocked Android, for which Map.of does not work.

Comment: the question is not specific to Android. and even if you don't want to use `Map.of`, it is bad practice to use double brace initialization

Comment: But how can this be done differently if this is bad practice?

Comment: with `put(key, value)`

Comment: put (new Pair <> (SystemsMeasures.Metric, SystemsMeasures.Imperial),
                        new MeasuresConversionFactor (2.2, 0.394));
Don't I do it?

Comment: in the constructor of `SystemsMeasuresConverter`